# How to get fragment's event, when it layouts it's child layouts?

Tags: android, layout, fragment

In my android studio project I have a fragment (the class is MainFragment) and a scrollview inside. In MainFragment class I want to get event, when the fragment already layout it's child views. i.e I want to call a method scrollview.getHeight() and not to get 0, because of the system has not yet calculated actual height of scrollview. Is there any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/2979171

Answer (score 1):

Do all the work on **@Resume**, in that time the fragment is created and the layout has been added so you should have the height

```
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // your code here ... 
  }
```

Comment: Again returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `onViewCreated` method. It is called when the view is created so you won't be getting 0 height from there.

```
@Overrride
void onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    scrollView.doOnPreDraw {
        println("Height: "+it.height)
        println("Mesured Height: "+it.measuredHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: Again returns 0.

Comment: @VahagChakhoyan i updated my answer. Please check now. Don't forget to upvote and mark as correct if it works! Let me know if it doesn't.